# What is a Strategy for Loose-Coupling Between Bundles in a Large Modular React+Redux Application

Tags: reactjs, redux

## Goal

I am looking for a React-Redux compatible way for an action or event in one part of a large modular application to trigger logic in another, loosely-coupled, part of the application. Something like a Pub-Sub system, that is compatible with React, Redux, and [Redux Code Splitting](https://redux.js.org/recipes/code-splitting).

## Scenario

- I have a React+Redux web application, which uses [code-splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) to lazy-load multiple bundles at runtime. The bundles contain code for: UI, Redux actions, Redux-Thunks, and Redux Reducers
- The Core module has some logic that allows a user to create notes, by entering text into a field, and clicking a button
- I would like for the dynamically-loaded bundles to be able to run custom-logic when new notes are created. This may include side-effects. The UI component may or may-note be rendered to the screen when the notes are created

## The Problem

Typically, in tightly-coupled modules, a redux-thunk action-creator (or similar) could be called from the Core module, to initiate side-effects, and  dispatch associated Redux actions as needed. However, with dynamically loaded bundles, references to the redux-thunk action creators are not available.

## Requirements

- Must avoid direct references *from* the Core module *to* the dynamic bundles, so as not to break code-splitting
- Must support "side-effects", such API calls, in the event consumer
- Must allow the dynamically loaded bundle logic to responded, even when the related UI components are not currently being displayed

## Ideas

- **Observables**: One idea is to leverage a pub-sub pattern with Observables, similar to the one described in [this article](https://medium.com/coding-stuff/pubsub-for-communicating-between-react-components-999159d59a77). However, I am concerned that this might violate some React-Redux best practice, break "time-travel" in the Redux dev tooling, and result in hard to catch bugs... or maybe it wont. With the React-Redux pattern, I am unsure of what kinds of side-effect are OK, and when.
- **Redux Middleware**: Write some custom Redux middleware to look for "Widget Creation" actions, and then trigger additional behavior. This feels like reinventing the wheel.

I am not a massive fan of either of the above. It seems like there is probably a much more straight-forward option I am missing

Thanks for any help

Comment: You want to give modules time to be ready by the time business logic runs, right? You can always use lifecycle events like `componentDidMount` within your lazy-loaded modules that invoke the actions you need. Have actions in your core app mount the modules, and then the module itself handle its own logic

Comment: @Andrew - thanks for the reply. I need for events to be handled even if the UI components are not currently being displayed (which I believe would mean non of their lifecycle events would fire). I'll update the question to clarify this.

Comment: Your state remains centralized? Or each module has it's own reducer?

Comment: Can you describe your exact situation that you want to implement something like this? This honestly doesn't sound a reasonable thing to do in a react app, unless you have some extraordinary circumstances.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Redux-Saga middleware](https://redux-saga.js.org/) for handling events?  Also, see the [Redux docs page on code splitting](https://redux.js.org/recipes/code-splitting), and the [`redux-dynostore`](https://github.com/ioof-holdings/redux-dynostore) and [`redux-dynamic-modules`](https://github.com/Microsoft/redux-dynamic-modules) packages for loading plugins.

Comment: @Dupocas - it has a single centralized store, and dynamically injects reducers using techniques described here: https://redux.js.org/recipes/code-splitting

Comment: @Andrew - it is a pluggable framework, where a user can add a note, and the note can be acted upon by the plugins.  The plugins are loaded using the techniques describe here: https://redux.js.org/recipes/code-splitting.

Comment: "I would like for dynamically-loaded modules to have the opportunity to respond to a Widget ". What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @markerikson - yes, I have looked at all those.  In fact, I am using redux-dynamic-modules, which works great, but doesn't include a strategy for responding to activity in sibling dynamic modules

Comment: @Dupocas:  I think the text-wrapping may have confused things. The full statement is: "I would like for dynamically-loaded modules to have the opportunity to respond to a Widget creation event".  So, basically, module A creates a Widget.  I would like for this to trigger logic in Module B, in a decoupled (or loosely-coupled) way.  Essentially a Pub-Sub model... except for it is not clear to me how this can be achieved inside a React & Redux framework

Answer (score 0):

[createListenerMiddleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware) would work well here. It is as standard implementation of the "Redux Middleware" option you mention.